Replace placeholders within shape groups Google slide using appscript
function copyShapes(copyCount) {
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  let group = slide.getGroups()[0];
  const xIncrement = 10;
  const yIncrement = 5.5;
  const initialX = 0.25;
  const initialY = 1;
  const maxCopiesPerPage = 10;
  for (let i = 0; i < copyCount; i++) {
    if (i % maxCopiesPerPage === 0) {
      if (i > 0) {
        group = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK).insertGroup(group);
      }
    } else {
      const positionIndex = i % maxCopiesPerPage;
      const row = Math.floor(positionIndex / 2);
      const col = positionIndex % 2;
      const x = cmToPoints(initialX + col * xIncrement);
      const y = cmToPoints(initialY + row * yIncrement);
      group.duplicate().setLeft(x).setTop(y);
    }
  }
}

First of all, there is 1 figure group in Google Slide. Here, how many copies I want, the copies of the shape group are created according to their positions. but there are placeholders in the group, {{NAME1}} and {{PRICE1}}, {{NAME1}}, {{NAME2}},{{NAME3}} and so on for as many placeholders as I want to create copies.
{{PRICE1}},{{PRICE2}},{{PRICE3}}
Let the copies change as, for example, if I want 4 copies{{PRICE1}},{{PRICE2}},{{PRICE3}},{{PRICE4}}
And
{{NAME1}}, {{NAME2}},{{NAME3}},{{NAME4}}
Let it change one by one like this
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1qFbwRUB4aCnfpMGIhMc_eCpKEMTZPkqHH52khxDJh6o/edit#slide=id.p
AND
https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/13-f6TrIUFYpN1qtkITIgX4-zd1fDtTTsJkDSMgkSiOjX_aibaVjQhG3Z/edit

Access the Textboxes Accordingly
When I examined your sample group, I noticed that the textboxes were not on the same group. I advise grouping multiple textboxes within shapes together so that they may be easier to access. One was deeper than the other. Upon examining the levels, I came up with the following script to access and increment the numbers when duplicating the shapes.
Script
function copyShapes(copyCount) {
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const xIncrement = 10;
  const yIncrement = 5;
  const initialX = 0;
  const initialY = 0.5;
  const maxCopiesPerPage = 10;
  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < copyCount; i++) {
    var slideNumber = Math.floor(i / maxCopiesPerPage);
    var group = slide.getGroups()[0];
    const positionIndex = i % maxCopiesPerPage;
    const row = Math.floor(positionIndex / 2);
    const col = positionIndex % 2;
    const x = cmToPoints(initialX + col * xIncrement);
    const y = cmToPoints(initialY + row * yIncrement);
    if (i % maxCopiesPerPage === 0) {
      if (i > 0) {
        group = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK).insertGroup(group);
        slide = presentation.getSlides()[slideNumber];
      }
    } else {
      group.duplicate().setLeft(x).setTop(y);
    }
    var newGroup = slide.getGroups()[i % maxCopiesPerPage];
    newGroup.getChildren()[0].asGroup().getChildren()[4].asShape().getText().setText("{{NAME" + (i + 1) + "}}"); //Name was deeper than Price
    newGroup.getChildren()[1].asShape().getText().setText("{{PRICE" + (i + 1) + "}}");
  }
}

Output
This was my output when I set the number of duplicates to 10:

References:

Class Group
Class PageElement
Class Shape


Please feel free to ask anything with respect to the answer posted above.

When I create 15 copies, 12 are created and there is an error on the 2nd page, it is reset to {{NAME1}}

Edited the code to be shorter. I saw recurring patterns to the code so I had to reduce it.

Please let me know if it worked on your side or there are still some bugs.

I'm curious about the grouping style of the figures and texts, how did you do it in that order?

Your original script already worked except for the texts. It duplicated your sample group. I merely added some lines of codes to directly point and change the texts on the textbox. However, i did manually check as to which group/child contained the texts so that really was the tricky part.
